# Bootstrap responsive table not responsive enough for text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried take a snippet of a page of search results, as shown in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/7n6tgbht/

The problem is that if you minimize the window, the results start to scale down but then it hits a point and overlaps the table. Any idea why this happens?

Using a standard table:

```
<table class="table table-responsive ">
....
</table>
```

So here is the table normally,

[image: Here is the table normally]

[image: And here is the table breaking]

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're looking for an easy fix just add this to your css

```
table td {
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

This will make all your lines wrap when the table won't scale any longer